# Python loop with dynamically named outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking into something that seems simple and I can only find complicated answers.

I'm doing some iterations on a function "BT" that yields several dataframes. I would like to get the "iterated" results directly as the output of my function, just differentiating them by their name.

I want i to vary from 1 to say 10 and label my output dataframes dynamically so that i can know to which "i" they correspond. Ideal code is below :)

```
 for i in range(10):
     start = dt.datetime(2017-i,12,31)
    'model_'%i, 'variation_'%i, 'rank_'%i, 'correl_'%i = BT(df_1, df_2)
```

I know I can achieve a similar result with dictionaries, but is there a quicker way, close to what is shown above?

Comment: _I know I can achieve a similar result with dictionaries, but is there a quicker way, close to what is shown above?_ I don't think there is.

Comment: If you don't want to use a dict, what about a list of [``collections.namedtuple``](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to define attributes dynamically because later in your code, you'd need to access them with static code (e.g. `model_1 + variation_2` or so). If you have a list of dataframes, the easiest way to make them accessible to the rest of your code is to actually store them as a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you were asking for, but you would normally use `list` and `namedtuple` for cases like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

MyData = namedtuple("MyData", ["model", "variation", "rank", "correl"])

data = []

for i in range(10):
     start = dt.datetime(2017-i,12,31)
    data.append(MyData(*BT(df_1, df_2)))

# e.g. access to single df
data[1].variation
```

An alternative would be to generate individual lists of items (which changes how you could access them later):

```
data = []

for i in range(10):
    start = dt.datetime(2017-i,12,31)
    data.append(BT(df_1, df_2))
model, variation, rank, correl = zip(*data)

# e.g. access to single df
variation[1]
```

There might be errors in the code since I don't know what the BT function does, but I hope this answer is still helpful.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I'll learn about namedtuple which I don't know yet! I think the second alternative is more suitable in this case, because of the way to access data afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
myList = []
for i in range(10):
     start = dt.datetime(2017-i,12,31)
     myList.append(("model_{0},model_{0},variation_{0},rank_{0},correl_{0}".format(i), BT(df_1, df_2))
```

Comment: Put a number inside `{}` (example 0) and you do not have to repeat i

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a nested dictionary:

```
data = {}
keys = ('model', 'variation', 'rank', 'correl')

for i in range(10):
    start = dt.datetime(2017-i,12,31)
    data[i] = dict(zip(keys, BT(df_1, df_2)))
```

Then access the first result `data[0]`.